# Preventing webpack-dev-server from recompiling on code change

Tags: javascript, webpack, webpack-dev-server

I have the property 'watch' set to false in my webpack.config.js files and this works as expected when I use webpack from the command line. However if I run a webpack-dev-server the files are watched for changes and recomplied when a change is made. Is there a way to prevent this?

Thanks

Adam

Comment: Have you tried setting [`devServer.hot: false`](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/#devserverhot) in your Webpack config?

Comment: Yeah, devServer.hot is set to false.